# Centering a custom view in a RelativeLayout using LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to center a custom view in relative layout.  This image rotates so it needs to be in the center of the layout so it doesn't go out of the layout bounds. Right now its displaying in the top left corner.   Here is my code:

---

```
container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_container);

bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.charlie_sheen);

rotate_view = new RotationView(this, bmap);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

rotate_view.setLayoutParams(params);
container.addView(rotate_view);
```

---

Here is my relative xml layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_container"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_1"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp" 
            android:padding="10dip" />
```

---

Do you have any ideas?  I know that there is probably a simple solution to this problmem, but I can't seem to find the answer.  Setting the LayoutParameter to center should center the view in the layour right?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Overall the code to add the custom view looks correct.  This may be a weak suggestion, but to rule out any issues that may have been cause by the view customization you could try modifying the code in one of two ways.

Option 1: Use the explicit form of `addRule()`, i.e.

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Option 2: Use the explicit form of `addView()` and don't set the params on the view itself, i.e.

```
//Omit the line above this one
container.addView(rotate_view, params);
```

Beyond that, perhaps some insight into the custom view, specifically how it measures itself (it's not trying to fill parent is it)?

HTH

Comment: He Devunwired, thanks for your help.  I tried your suggestions, and I'm still having the same problem.  I've overridden onMeasure in my custom view class based to be 100px larger than the bitmap.  (The bitmap will rotate so it needs some space to do this).  I've posted the code in a reply.  I've had some other ideas:                                                               -  I thought I could try adding the custom view to my xml layout as a custom view, and then inflating it

Comment: Can you verify that the image is centered inside of `RotationView`?  The easiest way to do this is give your custom view a background color, so you can see where its bounds really are in relation to its parent.  I suspect issue is somewhere inside `RotationView`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Devunwired I will do that.

Here is how I am centering the image now.

1) I am centering the image in my canvas using a BitmapDrawable setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) property.

2) I'm centering the RotationView in my Relative Layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/image_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/txt_1"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <com.mobicartel.acceldatatester.RotationView
       android:id="@+id/rotate_view"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'll add the background and let you know.  (Right now the image isn't displaying at all.  Sometimes you have to take a step backward to take two in the right direction!)